# How many license plates are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

If all license plates consist of characters from 4 - 6 length chosen from 26 letters and 10 digits (0-9):

- a)How many license plates are possible if repetition of symbols is
  allowed?
- b)How many license plates do not contain any repeated symbols?
- c)How many license plates have at least one repeated symbol?

My attempt:

- a) At first I thought it would be 36^6 but later realized characters
  can be 4-6,

so I think it is: $36^6 + 36^5 + 36^4$

- b) $P(36,31) + P(36,32) + P(36,33)$ ?
- c) So I think if it has 6 characters: $36\times36\times36\times36\times36\times1 = 36^5$ Then
  for the others $36^4$ and $36^3$

  So $36^5 + 36^4 + 36^3$ total?

Answer (score 3):

$(a)$ Ok.

$(b)^{36}P_{6} + ^{36}P_{5} + ^{36}P_{4}$

$(c)$ *Answer to $(a)$ - Answer to* $(b)$ [ The question says **at least one** repeated symbol  ]

Comment: b) do you mean it should be P(36,4) + P(32,5) + P(27,6) ?
and for C i thought it was just like a) except we have to make sure one of the character has to be repeating so we have only 1 choice for them.

Comment: From where has P(**32**,5) and P(**27**,6) come in ? I have expanded hint to a brief ans.